# Simple scripting for PR2

Tags: ros, python, robot, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm thinking about some super simple solution for controlling PR2. It should be understandable for newbies - students and allow them to make simple demos. Something like [cob_script_server](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_script_server). Is there something specific for PR2, or maybe is there existing configuration for mentioned script server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123166/simple-scripting-for-pr2/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few years ago when we were taking the PR2s to the Hack the Future event for kids, a few of us at Willow wrote the [pr2_hack_the_future](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_hack_the_future) stack, which includes a simple web interface, a script queue, and a simplified interface for interacting with the PR2: [pr2_simple_interface](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_hack_the_future/tree/master/pr2_simple_interface).

It's currently undocumented, unmaintained, and out of date, but it's probably still better than starting from nothing.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-28**:
Looks nice, thanks! I will definitely check it.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-28**:
There is even extended version of your code: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_script -> with documentation! :-)